# How to get looped database variable into jquery function

Tags: php, jquery

This must be an obvious answer but I can't find it anywhere.

I use php to generate a table of results for each row in a database.  Each table row has a delete button that deletes the db row based on a value 'custref'.  I would like an alert to pop up to confirm before taking you to the delete query but I'm struggling to pass the custref value to the delete page via the jquery alert. If I put the jquery in the head it is outside of the while loop so doesn't receive the custref value. If I put it inside the loop it gets called multiple times and doesn't work.

In the head:

```
 // show an alert before deleting
$('.delete').on('click', function(){
    $.confirm({
        title: 'Deleting Customer!',
        content: 'Are you sure?',
        type: 'red',
        buttons: {
            tryAgain: {
                text: 'Delete',
                btnClass: 'btn-red',
                action: function(){
                    location.href='actions/delete-enquiry.php?custref=$custref';
                }
            },
            close: function () {
            }
        }
    });
});
```

In the php while loop:

```
$custref = $row["custref"];

<input type='button' class='delete' value='DELETE' />
```

This literally outputs custref=$custref not the value relating to the row

Comment: Add your php code

Comment: This is not how you write php code in a web page. Are you really getting all the rows on your web page (forget about the delete function for now)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each customer has it's own delete button, you can set the onclick attribute to a function which accepts a parameter, in this case, the customer reference.

> This example uses both [JQuery](https://code.jquery.com/) and [Sweet Alert](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) plugins.

### PHP Example to create delete buttons:

```
$Customers = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
ForEach ($Customers AS $Customer) {
    Echo "<input type='button' onclick='deleteCustomer(\"$Customer\");' class='delete' value='DELETE $Customer' /><br /><br />";
}
```

### JQuery Code to display a confirm dialog, then processes if true:

```
function deleteCustomer(CustomerRef) {
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
            Swal.fire(
                'Deleted!',
                'Customer number ' + CustomerRef + ' has been deleted.',
                'success'
            )}
        // Redirect to your deletion script. Could also use AJAX
        location.href='actions/delete-enquiry.php?custref=' + CustomerRef;
    })
}
```

See [here](https://so.amarokstudios.com/Test?Number=50) for an example.